# How to use Taylor 's formula to evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {e^x \sin x -x (1+x)}{x^3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion

> Use Taylor 's Formula to evaluate the following limit: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {e^x \sin x -x (1+x)}{x^3}.$$

Could anyone help me in solving this please?

Comment: Please show your work!

Comment: I have seen his posts. Most of them don't have his work while asking something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The Taylor series of $e^x\sin(x)$ about $0$ is $x+x^2+\frac{x^3}3+\cdots$

Comment: did you multiplied the Maclurine series of them ...... what about the other part of the numerator?

Comment: Yes, I computed the first terms of$$\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}6+\cdots\right)\left(x-\frac{x^3}6+\cdots\right).$$Now, subtract from that the other part of the numerator.

Comment: how many terms you computed and why this number exactly?

Comment: I just went up to dgree $3$. That's all I need, since the denominator of your expression is $x^3$.

Comment: so you multiplied the first 3 terms of the maclurine series of e^x by the first term only of the maclurine series of sine ?

Comment: No. As you can see from my first comment, I multiplied it by the first **four** terms of the MacLaurin series of $e^x$.

Comment: the final answer will be 1/3 .... correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: If I want to use the Taylor formula to  evaluate $\sqrt {5}$ to the accuracy of 10^{-4} .... where can I plug this accuracy number?

Comment: That's another question. I suggest that you post it as such.

Comment: there is a similar one here but the difference is in the accuracy https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221318/calculate-sqrt5-using-taylor-series-to-the-accuracy-of-3-digit-after-the-po

Comment: I have just posted my new question .... could you please check it?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2989773/h-use-the-taylor-formula-to-evaluate-sqrt-5-to-the-accuracy-of-10-4